# ¿Cómo puedo dividir una hora php?

Tags: php

estoy usando diff para sacar la diferencia de una hora a otra.

```
$hrs=['2021/08/11 08:00:00 AM','2021/08/11 08:00:00 PM'];
    $fecha1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d h:i:s A', $hrs[0]);
    $fecha2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d h:i:s A', $hrs[1]);
    $interval = $fecha1->diff($fecha2);

    echo $interval->format('%H:%I:%S');
```

esto me da como resultado **12:00:00**

Pero ahora necesito dividir esa hora entre otro numero.

ej:

12:00:00 div entre 10

12 horas divididos entre 10 me daría 01:12.

teniendo en cuenta:
las dos primeras horas las que use para sacar la diferencia.

hr1: 08:00:00 AM
hr2: 08:00:00 PM

debo hacer lo siguiente:

ya sabemos que hay 12 horas de diferencia
y que si dividimos 12 horas entre 10 le corresponde a cada 1 01:12.

el resultado final seria así:

partiendo desde la hr1:
08:00:00 AM.

debe sumar a cada hora el resultado de la división:

ejemplo

1: 08:00:00 AM + 01:12:00 AM = 09:12:00 AM.

2: 09:12:00 AM + 01:12:00 AN = 10:24:00 AM

3: ------ Y así sucesivamente.

Nota: lo que me tiene confundido es que no sé como hacer la división de las horas por x cantidad.

agradezco las críticas y ayuda.

Comment: Si la precisión que necesitas es en segundos, una aproximación inicial sería convertirlo a segundos, operar en segundos e ir añadiendo la cantidad de segundos que dé tu división. Ya habría que ver si hay alguna funcionalidad propia de PHP para hacer esto mismo :)

Comment: si eso quiero saber.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Podrías hacerlo con [`DateInterval()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.dateinterval.php) y [`DatePeriod()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.dateperiod.php).

Primeramente, obtenemos cuántas horas hay (en minutos) en el intervalo entre ambas fechas. Luego creamos un período en el que las horas vayan ocurriendo según ese intervalo (72 minutos para este caso).

Por ejemplo:

```
$hrs=['2021/08/11 08:00:00 AM','2021/08/11 08:00:00 PM'];
$fecha1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d h:i:s A', $hrs[0]);
$fecha2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d h:i:s A', $hrs[1]);
$interval = $fecha1->diff($fecha2);
$divideBy=10;

$minutes= "PT".($interval->h / $divideBy * 60)."M";
$period = new DatePeriod($fecha1, new DateInterval($minutes), $fecha2);
foreach ($period as $dt) {
    echo $dt->format("H:i:s A\n");
}
```

**Salida:**

```
08:00:00 AM
09:12:00 AM
10:24:00 AM
11:36:00 AM
12:48:00 PM
14:00:00 PM
15:12:00 PM
16:24:00 PM
17:36:00 PM
18:48:00 PM
```

Si necesitas mayor precisión o calcular en base a otros rangos temporales también puedes hacerlo. Revisa en el [Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/dateinterval.construct.php) los diferentes períodos con los que puedes trabajar. Aquí hemos construido algo así: `PT72M` que significa un período de 72 minutos. Pero puedes trabajar también con segundos, horas, días, años, semanas, meses...

Por ejemplo, si en vez de minutos quieres trabajar con segundos, sólo tendrías que multiplicar de nuevo por `60` y cambiar la `M` por la `S` en esta línea: `$minutes= "PT".($interval->h / 10 * 60 * 60)."S"`.

El resultado sería el mismo como podrás ver:

```
$hrs=['2021/08/11 08:00:00 AM','2021/08/11 08:00:00 PM'];
$fecha1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d h:i:s A', $hrs[0]);
$fecha2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d h:i:s A', $hrs[1]);
$interval = $fecha1->diff($fecha2);
$divideBy=10;
$minutes= "PT".($interval->h / $divideBy * 60 * 60)."S";
$period = new DatePeriod($fecha1, new DateInterval($minutes), $fecha2);
foreach ($period as $dt) {
    echo $dt->format("H:i:s A\n");
}
```

**Salida:**

```
08:00:00 AM
09:12:00 AM
10:24:00 AM
11:36:00 AM
12:48:00 PM
14:00:00 PM
15:12:00 PM
16:24:00 PM
17:36:00 PM
18:48:00 PM
```

Cabe decir que dentro del bucle, `$dt` será siempre un objeto `DateTime` y que podrás trabajar con él con toda la potencialidad que te ofrece la clase `DateTime` de PHP, usando todos los métodos y propiedades de dicha clase.

Comment: gracias, amigo y si quiero guardar los datos en un array de la siguiente manera. array("hora_ini"=>"08:00:00 AM","hora_fin"=>"09:12:00") y así sucesivamente array("hora_ini"=>"09:12:00 AM","hora_fin"=>"10:24:00") no se si me entiendes, todo en un solo array.

Comment: @CRIS19N interesante planteamiento, pero dado que Stackoverflow funciona por preguntas, sugiero que plantees una nueva pregunta con esta duda (puedes hacer referencia a esta pregunta). Planteando una nueva pregunta el sitio se enriquece y podrás tener otras posibles respuestas de otros usuarios.

Comment: @CRIS19N se me ocurre algo así: `$mData=array(); foreach ($period as $dt) { $newDate = clone $dt; $newDate->add(new DateInterval($minutes)); $mData[]=array('hora_ini'=>$dt, 'hora_fin'=>$newDate);}` Clonamos el objeto en cada iteracción y le agregamos los minutos, así obtenemos en cada paso la `hora_fin`  y todo eso irá guardado en un array `$mData`.

Comment: gracias! @A. Cedano

Answer (score 2):

Podrías intentar convertirlo todo a segundos y calcularlo de ese modo.

Acá se obtuvo el string que tienes, se convierten horas en minutos,
 y se suman con los minutos, para repetir lo mismo al convertirlo en segundos.
Luego trabajamos los segundos para hacer la division.

```
<?php
$hora = "12:10:26";
$divisor = "10";
echo $hora."</br>";
list($horas, $minutos, $segundos) = explode(":", $hora);
$minutos += $horas * 60;
echo $minutos." minutos totales</br>";
$segundos += $minutos * 60;
echo $segundos." segundos totales</br>";
date_default_timezone_set("UTC"); //Zona horaria por si es necesario
echo "Resultado: " . date("h:i:s", $segundos / $divisor);
```